# Remove specific string using RegExp

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a different string:

```
Word1-A-OK
Word2-Sample-R-OK
Word3-A
```

How can remove these `(-A, -A-OK, -A-NG, -R, -R-OK, -R-NG, -W, -C)` strings using Regexp? The output I would want is:

```
Word1
Word2-Sample
Word3
```

This is my current RegExp:

```
(\\.|-A|[^\w]+R|[^\w]+OK|[^\w]+NG|[^\w]+W|[^\w]+C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this.  Just do a regex replacement on the following alternation:

```
-(?:[AR](?:-(?:OK|NG))?|W|C)$
```

Then, replace with empty string to effectively remove these suffixes.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a big help

Answer (score 1):

You could match for the example data

```
-[AR](?:-OK)?
```

And replace with an empty string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vBJdFb/1)

To match all of the combinations

```
(\w+)-(?:[AR](?:-(?:NG|OK))?|[WC])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMHux1/1)

And replace with group 1.